# Communicating to the restful web services in Phonegap

Tags: android, json, rest, cordova, sencha-touch

I want to built a mobile application using Phonegap that will  communicate with the restful web services and parse the json data.There are two ways two do it:

1. Calling restful web services using http connection in Java and connecting the Java code to JavaScript file by making our own plug-in in cordova.

   2.Making ajax calls to communicate with rest services.

Which one is better considering the needs below:

1.It can call https web service,since for https in android we need to include certificates,create bks file for that which includes lot of mess.

2.It should be able to receive and parse the json data and render it to the html page.

3.We need to built this app for primarily android OS but if we can built it for ios,windows etc. It would be better.

Please tell me if i am using right tool,if sencha touch is easier to perform these tasks?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you choose PhoneGap, it is an indication that you are wanting to re-use your HTML/JS/CSS expertise as much as possible. Say if you choose jQuery Mobile (or any other framework) for your project, jquery provides ajax for your needs already and there is no reason to go down to the JAVA layer.

That said, the right approach should be using the ajax mechanism provided by your javascript framework. This is your option-2 and you won't need to build the raw ajax utilizes. Like if you go with jQuery/jQueryMobile + Backbone + backbone.marionette (we happen to use them in phoneGap app), there are a lot of add-ons out there to help. Like in this [example](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette), it is actually part of the phoneGap app under 'www' directory.

Also the communication to the webservice is your least concern if you have all the tools.  Making suggestion on what tools to use is not allowed by Stackoverflow:-)

Comment: Thanks Ming for your suggestions.

Comment: Please make more comments,suggestions please.

Comment: All the suggestions pointing to is that you should use Ajax from the javascript framework that you plan to use.  This will be your option-2.

Comment: How to send cookies in REST requests? (As there are no cookies in cordova)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use AJAX because it completely fits all your needs, and you gain to use the same code for future use if you'll ever decide to build for more platforms.

moreover, why make things complicated? you already writing your app using javascript, so don't mix it with native code when its unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Liran for your suggestions.